"Makefile:7: recipe for target 'link' failed" error compiling c++for smfl
I will learn SFML for C++. I want to install SFML in Vscode but after this code
mingw32-make -f Makefile
I get this error:
g++ -Isrc/include -c coding/*.cpp
g++ *.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'    
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf11CircleShapeC1Efj'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Color5GreenE'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Shape12setFillColorERKNS_5ColorE'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK2sf10WindowBase6isOpenEv'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf10WindowBase9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderTarget4drawERKNS_8DrawableERKNS_12RenderStatesE'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev[__ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'       
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev[__ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev[__ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5ShapeD2Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'link' failed
mingw32-make: *** [link] Error 1

What is the solution to this error?
main.cpp :
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

Makefile :
all: compile link

compile: 
    g++ -Isrc/include -c coding/*.cpp

link:
    g++ *.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

I have taken care of my minGW installations and all other details, but when I proceeded through the steps, I encountered this problem.I also made my path settings in my json file as follows: " "C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"] " Please help.

Your code compiles for me, with the exact same compiler flags. You likely downloaded a version of SFML incompatible with your compiler (x32 with x64 compiler, or vice versa, or something else). Consider reinstalling both mingw and sfml from msys2: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075 (which is what I've tested on)

-Lsrc/lib could be where you made your mistake. Why didn't you just use pacman to install the proper SFML binaries for your compiler? The official VSCode MinGW instructions tell you to install MinGW using msys2 so you should have pacman and the large set of packages from the msys2 repository.
